# X509Certificate2 Access Denied

Tags: openssl, x509certificate2

I have been trying to upgrade OpenSSL from 0.9.8 to 1.0.1 version. Creating a X509Certificate2 certificate which was working all good earlier now fails with

***Application error log***:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

I have tried all the possible solutions that i could find in the forum but in vain.

**Code snippet**:

```
public static X509Certificate2 _signerCert = null;
byte[] pfxData; string pfxPassword;
GetRootCertificate(out pfxData, out pfxPassword);

lock (_lockObjectSigner) {
                        _signerCert = new X509Certificate2(pfxData, pfxPassword);
                    }
```

***Security event log***:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>5061</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12290</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-05-31T05:48:49.268222200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>33990</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="500" ThreadID="4960" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>EMM-DMZ-SUS2.EMMDMZ.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-20</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">EMM-DMZ-SUS2$</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">EMMDMZ</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e4</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProviderName">Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider</Data> 
  <Data Name="AlgorithmName">RSA</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyName">{A7C2BCEE-EC9F-49EA-92A6-666C0F2987DD}</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyType">%%2499</Data> 
  <Data Name="Operation">%%2481</Data> 
  <Data Name="ReturnCode">0x80090010</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**Options tried:**

```
public static X509Certificate2 _signerCert = null;
byte[] pfxData; string pfxPassword;
GetRootCertificate(out pfxData, out pfxPassword);

lock (_lockObjectSigner) {
                        _signerCert = new X509Certificate2(pfxData, pfxPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
                    }
```

Enabling IIS Application Pool configuration (Application Pools > Advanced Settings) to load the user profile for the application pool identity user.

Changing AppPool's identity to NetworkService/LocalService?

Manually adding administrator rights on the Microsoft keys folder "C:\programdata\Microsoft\Crypto".

Kindly let me know if there is any other option thats worth a try?

Regards
Narik